# Output variables one by one from array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how do I pull variables from array one by one? I want to make a card with one saying Zlin, second Praha, etc... The way it works now is that it outputs all of them at once 4x. Thank you.

```
   const KartyLoop = () => {
    var mesta = ['Zlin','Praha','Ostrava','Brno']
    var lokace = []
    for (var i=0; i < mesta.length; i++)
    {
        lokace += mesta + "\n"
    }
return (<Text>{lokace}</Text>);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by output? Your question is not clear enough

Comment: The output of this function should be text. The output is the return().
return (<Text>{lokace}</Text>);

Comment: You add the whole `mesta` to `lokace` instead of one of its items. Try adding `mesta[i]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code pushes the array itself and not its values.
If I understand correctly you want to copy an array.

You would want to do this.

```
const KartyLoop = () => {
    var mesta = ['Zlin','Praha','Ostrava','Brno']
    var lokace = []
    for (var i=0; i < mesta.length; i++)
    {
        lokace += mesta[i] + "\n"
    }
    return (lokace);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exacly what i was looking for. I am new in this language so I'm still learning 

Comment: @TomášGabriel No problem, if my solution helped you out don't forget to mark as solved! Have a nice one.